# How to use Ember model attributes in controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  things: DS.hasMany('match', {async: true, defaultValue: []})
});
```

I can iterate through the `things` in a template:

```
{{#each model.things as |thing|}}
    <h3>thing.title</h3>
{{/each}}
```

But I don't want all of the things. I only want to display some of them. And which I will display will depend on a controller variable. So my thought is that I would have a computed property in the controller, as follows:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  state: 0,
  displayThings: function() {
    var things = this.get('model').things;
    var state = this.get('state');
    // do stuff, filter in a way that isn't important
    return things;
  }.property('state')
});
```

Forgetting the filtering for now, if I try to iterate through these `displayThings` as follows:

```
{{#each displayThings as |thing|}}
    <h3>thing.title</h3>
{{/each}}
```

Nothing shows up in the template. I can verify with `console.log` that the  `thing`s are in the controller property, and some object is getting sent to the template, but not an object that can be iterated, somehow.

I'm using Ember 1.13.

Comment: Don't you want `this.get('model.things')`? By the way, the default value for `things` is unnecessary. Also, realize your `displayThings` computed property is returning `things`. Don't you want it to return some filtered version of `things` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The key part of filtering is not included in your code, and there might lie the reason why what you're getting returned from `displayThings` is not iterable or something. Also, as @torazaburo points out in a comment to your question, you're returning `things`, and you might want to return a filtered version of things.

And lastly, and very important, your `displayThings` property should depend not only on `state`, but also on `model.things` or some variation of it, depending on the actual filtering. For instance, if you're filtering the `things` collection by a specific field `status`, then `displayThings` should also have a dependency declared like shown below:

```
displayThings: Ember.computed('state', 'model.things.@each.status', function() {
  // ...
})
```

If your filtering condition is more complex than just depending on one or two fields of the collection's items, then maybe you can declare dependency on the whole collection objects, like this:

```
displayThings: Ember.computed('state', 'model.things.[]', function() {
  // ...
})
```

The code above states that if the `things` collection changes, or any of the objects in it change in any way, then the `displayThings` property is re-computed.

Now, back to your original question, I'll give it a crack by posting here a complete version of your controller code with an actual hypothetical filtering being done. Perhaps you could apply your actual filtering criteria by modifying this code:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  state: 0,
  displayThings: Ember.computed('state', 'model.things.@each.status', function() {
    var state = this.get('state');
    return this.get('model.things').filter(function(thing) {
      return thing.get('status') > state;
    });
  })
});
```

The above controller will expose in `displayThings` a collection of all `things` whose `status` is strictly greater than the controller's `state` property. This should do the trick, and should be easily adapted to some other filtering criteria by changing the filtering function, and updating the dependency declaration correspondingly, as explained above.

Comment: Your observer calculates the filtered data but the return value will not go anywhere. It should be `Ember.computed` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes thanks. You're totally right. For some reason I wrote `observer` every time I meant `computed` in the code. I fixed the code samples now.